# Roman numerals footnotes only in title page

Tags: arabic, roman

I am trying to use roman numerals for the footnote only in the title page using `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\Roman{footnote}}`. I have also tried by using `minipage`, but it seems it simply does not work properly inside `\titlepage`. 
Is there a straightforward way to use roman numerals only in the title page and arabic usual numbering in the rest?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\Roman{footnote}}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage} 
\begin{Large}
\textsc{Title\footnote{This must have roman numerals.}}
\end{Large}
\end{titlepage} 
\section{A section}
Some text\footnote{And this, arabic.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you really need a footnote on a title page?  Please edit your question to show a minimal compilable document that shows what the problem is.

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes, this is a MSc Thesis and title page must refer in footnotes some references (emails, institution, etc.). (Hey @Kurt)

Answer (score 2):

The following works both with `\maketitle` and the `{titlepage}` environment. You need to wrap the redefinition and the title page (environment) or `\maketitle` in a group. `{... }`.  If you are using `article` class, you also need to reset the footnote counter to `0`; for `report` or `book` class you don't.

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{A title}
\author{An author\footnote{A Roman numbered footnote}}
\date{}
\begin{document}
% Note the {}
{%
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\Roman{footnote}}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{Large}
\textsc{Title\footnote{This must have roman numerals.}}
\end{Large}
\end{titlepage}
\setcounter{footnote}{0}}
}
\chapter{A chapter}
Some text\footnote{An arabic numbered footnote}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, this seems really straightforward. What happens if I use `\begin{titlepage} ... \end{titlepage}` without a `\maketitle`statement?

Comment: @cwasdwa That's why you need to post a minimal example with your question... (But did you try it?)

Comment: @AllanMunn Yes sir, I edited it now with a simple version of my case, with `article`class.